# Trying to provide webgl with a random color when the user clicks on a falling block

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user clicks on the falling block it pauses, and when clicked on again it unpauses. I am trying to figure out how to make it so that once you pause the block it changes to a random color and then when unpaused it will then change again to a another random color. I am not too familiar with WebGL. [Here is the source code.](https://jsfiddle.net/305kecn9/4/)
Would I need to add a render function? 
and then add

```
function checkclickPressed(e) {

if (e.keyCode == "0") {
    color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
    alert("left click pressed");
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dirty solution.
Your falling block's color is determined by:

```
rainingRect.color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
gl.clearColor(rainingRect.color[0], rainingRect.color[1], rainingRect.color[2], 1.0);
```

Inside your

```
if (!paused) {

  }
```

code block - where you update the score and pause the game, you could simply add the above lines to change the color. The problem is, that your drawAnimation() function doesn't get called anymore so your canvas wouldn't be updated with the new color.
Furthermore, if we simply call drawAnimation inside the if-block it would start firing every 17ms again because of the setTimeout timer inside.
So I recommend adding a paramter which controls if the timer should restart or not.

```
  function drawAnimation(repeat) {
    gl.scissor(rainingRect.position[0], rainingRect.position[1],
      rainingRect.size[0], rainingRect.size[1]);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    rainingRect.position[1] -= rainingRect.velocity;
    if (rainingRect.position[1] < 0) {
      misses += 1;
      missesDisplay.innerHTML = misses;
      rainingRect = new Rectangle();
    }
    // We are using setTimeout for animation. So we reschedule
    // the timeout to call drawAnimation again in 17ms.
    // Otherwise we won't get any animation.
    if (repeat) {
      timer = setTimeout(drawAnimation, 17, true);
    }
  }
```

Now you can safely call **drawAnimation(false);** to update your canvas once. Just remember to make it true for all other calls to drawAnimation.
So after setting the color to a random new one and calling drawAnimation, you have to set a new color once more. This will be visible as soon as the game continues.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict"
  window.addEventListener("load", setupAnimation, false);
  var gl,
    timer,
    rainingRect,
    scoreDisplay,
    missesDisplay,
    status,
    paused = false;

  function setupAnimation(evt) {
    window.removeEventListener(evt.type, setupAnimation, false);
    if (!(gl = getRenderingContext()))
      return;
    gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

    rainingRect = new Rectangle();
    timer = setTimeout(drawAnimation, 17, true);
    document.querySelector("canvas")
      .addEventListener("click", playerClick, false);
    var displays = document.querySelectorAll("strong");
    scoreDisplay = displays[0];
    missesDisplay = displays[1];
    status = displays[2];
  }

  var score = 0,
    misses = 0;

  function drawAnimation(repeat) {
    gl.scissor(rainingRect.position[0], rainingRect.position[1],
      rainingRect.size[0], rainingRect.size[1]);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    rainingRect.position[1] -= rainingRect.velocity;
    if (rainingRect.position[1] < 0) {
      misses += 1;
      missesDisplay.innerHTML = misses;
      rainingRect = new Rectangle();
    }
    // We are using setTimeout for animation. So we reschedule
    // the timeout to call drawAnimation again in 17ms.
    // Otherwise we won't get any animation.
    if (repeat) {
      timer = setTimeout(drawAnimation, 17, true);
    }
  }

  function playerClick(evt) {
    // We need to transform the position of the click event from
    // window coordinates to relative position inside the canvas.
    // In addition we need to remember that vertical position in
    // WebGL increases from bottom to top, unlike in the browser
    // window.
    var position = [
      evt.pageX - evt.target.offsetLeft,
      gl.drawingBufferHeight - (evt.pageY - evt.target.offsetTop),
    ];
    // if the click falls inside the rectangle, we caught it.
    // Increment score and create a new rectangle.
    var diffPos = [position[0] - rainingRect.position[0],
      position[1] - rainingRect.position[1]
    ];
    if (diffPos[0] >= 0 && diffPos[0] < rainingRect.size[0] &&
      diffPos[1] >= 0 && diffPos[1] < rainingRect.size[1]) {
      score += 1;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      // rainingRect = new Rectangle();
      if (!paused) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        paused = true;
        rainingRect.color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
        gl.clearColor(rainingRect.color[0], rainingRect.color[1], rainingRect.color[2], 1.0);
        drawAnimation(false);
        rainingRect.color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
        gl.clearColor(rainingRect.color[0], rainingRect.color[1], rainingRect.color[2], 1.0);
        status.innerHTML = 'Paused';
      } else {

        timer = setTimeout(drawAnimation, 17, true);
        paused = false;
        status.innerHTML = 'Playing';

      }
    }
  }

  function Rectangle() {
    // Keeping a reference to the new Rectangle object, rather
    // than using the confusing this keyword.
    var rect = this;
    // We get three random numbers and use them for new rectangle
    // size and position. For each we use a different number,
    // because we want horizontal size, vertical size and
    // position to be determined independently.
    var randNums = getRandomVector();
    rect.size = [
      5 + 120 * randNums[0],
      5 + 120 * randNums[1]
    ];
    rect.position = [
      randNums[2] * (gl.drawingBufferWidth - rect.size[0]),
      gl.drawingBufferHeight
    ];
    rect.velocity = 1.0 + 6.0 * Math.random();
    rect.color = getRandomVector();
    gl.clearColor(rect.color[0], rect.color[1], rect.color[2], 1.0);

    function getRandomVector() {
      return [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
    }
  }

  function getRenderingContext() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") ||
      canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    if (!gl) {
      var paragraph = document.querySelector("p");
      paragraph.innerHTML = "Failed to get WebGL context." +
        "Your browser or device may not support WebGL.";
      return null;
    }
    gl.viewport(0, 0,
      gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    return gl;

    function checkKeyPressed(e) {

    }

    function checkclickPressed(e) {

    }
  }
})();
```

```css
<style>body {
  text-align: center;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  display: block;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.6em;
}

</style>
```

```html
<p>You caught
  <strong>0</strong>. You missed
  <strong>0</strong> Status
  <strong>Playing</strong>.</p>
<canvas>Your browser does not seem to support
    HTML5 canvas.</canvas>
```

Here's the full example - hit 'Run code snippet' to see it in action: